# How to remove the error in VS code : no such file or directory?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, cs50

I know there are many answers on web for the Q I asked , but I have given a whole day to resolve that but nothing work

```
PS G:\IP folder\cse\week 1  c> cd "g:\IP folder\cse\week 1  c\" ; 
if ($?) { gcc hello.c -o hello } ; if ($?) { .\hello }
hello.c:1:11: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory
1 | # include <cs50.h>
  |           ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I am a beginner to C language so did everything thats been already on web like re-installing MinGW , adding bin to paths, etc. But nothing works. Please give a solution so that I dont get this problem in future too.

p.s. I have installed Mingw in C drive and my cse folder is in G drive

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Instead copy&paste your code and error messages as formatted text into your question. As you already know, you must include `cs50.h`. Therefore it is rather pointless to show what happens if you don't do it.

Comment: Did you copy `cs50.h` into your compiler's include folder? Or did you copy it in the same folder where your own code is? You probably need to include `"cs50.h"` instead of `<cs50.h>`. Or .... did you download cs50 source and header files at all?

Comment: i have not downloaded cs50 source and header files because the lecture I was watching had started using the vs code right away without downloading anything

Comment: and i have no idea about the compilers include folder

Comment: `cs50.h` is not a standard C header. It is provided by cs50 course. Together with `cs50.c`. There must be some download instruction in the cs50 documentation. Without those files you cannot compile any example from cs50 course.

Comment: thanks  but none of the things worked , and i shifted to web version of vs code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254245/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-universe-a7).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```c
#include "cs50.h"
```